# C++ CLI Class problem

Tags: c++-cli

----- hello, world 2.cpp -----

```
// Hello, World 2.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "hello.h"
#include <string>

using namespace System;
using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    hello hi = new hello("Bob", "Blacksmith");
    Console::WriteLine(L"Hello, " + hi.getName + "!");
    return 0;
}
```

----- hello.h -----

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef HELLO_H
#define HELLO_H

class hello
{
private:
    string _fname;
    string _lname;
    //hello() { } // private default constructor

public:
    hello(string fname, string lname);
    void SetName(string fname, string lname);
    string GetName();

};

#endif
```

----- hello.cpp -----

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "hello.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

hello::hello(string fname, string lname)
{
    SetName(fname, lname);
}

void hello::SetName(string fname, string lname)
{
    _fname = fname;
    _lname = lname;
}

string hello::getName()
{
    return _fname + _lname;
}
```

----- The errors -----

- ------ Build started: Project: Hello, World 2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
- Hello, World 2.cpp
- Hello, World 2.cpp(12): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'hello *' to 'hello'
- No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
- Hello, World 2.cpp(13): error C2039: 'getName' : is not a member of 'hello'
- \documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cpp\hello, world 2\hello, world 2\hello.h(8) : see declaration of 'hello'
- hello.cpp
- hello.cpp(17): error C2039: 'getName' : is not a member of 'hello'
- \documents\visual studio 2010\projects\cpp\hello, world 2\hello, world 2\hello.h(8) : see declaration of 'hello'
- hello.cpp(19): error C2065: '_fname' : undeclared identifier
- hello.cpp(19): error C2065: '_lname' : undeclared identifier
- Generating Code...
  ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Answer (score 5):

Error messages tell you exactly where and what the problems are, though they can be a bit intimidating at first. Maybe I can help demystify them a bit:

> Hello, World 2.cpp(12): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'hello *' to 'hello'

This means that on line 12 in Hello, World 2.cpp, you're trying to put a pointer to `hello` (the return from `new`) inside `hi` which is not a pointer type. Since you don't need a dynamically allocated object here, just drop the `new`.

In situations where you do need a dynamically allocated object, you would change the `hi` variable to `hello *` and add a corresponding `delete`.

> Hello, World 2.cpp(13): error C2039: 'getName' : is not a member of 'hello'

C++ is case sensitive. In one file you have `GetName`, in the other you have `getName`. Pick one.

> hello.cpp(19): error C2065: '_fname' : undeclared identifier
>   hello.cpp(19): error C2065: '_lname' : undeclared identifier

Line 19 of hello.cpp is the definition of the lower case `getName`. Since `getName` wasn't declared in the class (see previous error), the compiler has no idea what `_fname` or `_lname` are. These errors will go away once the original problems are solved.

**Edit**

See @Sergey's answer for some other more general observations of things to fix.

Answer (score 3):

The `new` keyword creates a pointer - if you do it this way, 'hi' should be declared as `hello*`, or you should reqrite the declaration as:

```
hello hi(...);
```

The second error is just due to case sensitivity (getName, GetName).

Answer (score 1):

```
hello hi = new hello("William", "Dyson");
```

Must be

```
hello* hi = new hello(...);
```

Or

```
 hello hi("William", "Dyson");  ;

Console::WriteLine(L"Hello, " + hi.getName + "!");
```

Must be

```
Console::WriteLine(L"Hello, " + hi.getName() + "!");
```

There may be other failures but i have to go now.

Comment: L"Hello, "? Isn't that a wide-string literal that become implicitly cast to Char*, and then to System::String?

Answer (score 1):

There are several errors.

- File names with whitespaces. Not critical, but can lead to problems
- `Console::WriteLine(L"Hello, " + hi.getName + "!");`

this should be something like this:

```
 string s("Hello, ");
 s += hi->getName();
 s += "!"
 Console::WriteLine(s);
```

- delete objects allocated with new: `delete hi;`
- `string hello::getName()` should be `string hello::GetName()`
- Never use the `use namespace ...` in header files
- Include other files within guard block

Answer (score 0):

Some comments that undoubtedly will be posted before I'm finished writing this:

1. Put you public members first
2. the namespace `System` implies Managed C++, if you don't know what that is and think you are using plain C++, please read about `printf` and `std::cout`.
3. The line

   `hello hi = new hello("William", "Dyson");`

   should read

   `hello hi("William", "Dyson");` or `hello* hi = new hello("William", "Dyson");`

   The first creates an object on the stack (which will be automatically destructed as it goes out of scope. The second creates a pointer to an object on the heap, which you will have to `delete` before the pointer goes out of scope (after you've finished with it)
4. about `hello::getName()`: you have typos with regards to capitalization (getname vs getName) and it should be declared like this (in header and accordingly in the source file):

   `const string getName() const;`

   The first const is optional, but I like it that way, the last one lets you call this function from a `const hello` object, and tells the reader that the function does not modify the object.
5. You should pass `string` by reference (here is a correcter constructor):

   `hello( const string &fname, const string& lname);`
6. Sources and headers should have names without spaces (or special characters) in them, this will be problematic for UNIX<->Windows if you're not careful.

That's all I can see right now.

Comment: Public members first or not is just a matter of taste. And printf() is not C++.

Comment: "You should pass string by reference": This is better advice if the strings aren't being copied inside the function. If you are planning to make a copy, it's better to make the copy implicit (pass by value) and let the compiler figure out how best to optimize.

Comment: @codymanix: agreed, yet a LOT of people use it. I avoid it like the plague.
@ Cogwheel: agreed, but it won't hurt to get in the habit of passing `const` references as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate something with `new` you have to call `delete` after you don't need it anymore.

In case you want to use the garbage collector the clean up for you you have to declare the class as `ref class hello` and then instantiate it with:

```
hello^ hi = gcnew hello(...);
```